# returning a list of objects with HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django

I have a view that add and edit `Meeting` objects and I'm going to after saving a `Meeting` object show a list of participants of that object,how can I return a list of participants with `HttpResponseRedirect` ? I don't think it be possible to send a big list of objects via `query string` !

in `views.py`

```
def addMeeting(request,meeting_id=None):
   message=u''
   participants=Participant.objects.filter(meeting__id=meeting_id)
   if request.GET.get('save'):
      message='your recorded was registered'
   if meeting_id:
      meeting_instance=Meeting.objects.get(pk=meeting_id)
   else:
      meeting_instance=Meeting()
   if request.method=='POST':
      meetingform=MeetingForm(request.POST,instance=meeting_instance)
      if meetingform.is_valid():
         meeting=meetingform.save()
         meeting.save()
         redirect_url=reverse('MeetingManagerHub.views.addMeeting', args=[meeting.pk])
         return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url+'?save=True')
   else:
      meetingform=MeetingForm(instance=meeting_instance)
   return render_to_response('MeetingHub/addmeeting.html', {'meetingform': meetingform,'message':message},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in `urls.py`

```
(r'^meeting/add/$','MeetingManagerHub.views.addMeeting'),
(r'^meeting/add/(?P<meeting_id>\d+)/$','MeetingManagerHub.views.addMeeting'),
```

I googled alot and finally found out that HttpResponseRedirect just redirect us to a new address and doesn't work with `context`!

how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a secret to this.  A Redirect should points to a view which gets the meeting AND the participants.

Often, that's a simple view function that handles simple GET requests and returns the meeting and the list of participants.

If you're going to redirect back to this `addMeeting` view function, then the GET processing needs to query meetings AND the participants.
That means that the `render_to_response` must include the meeting AND the participants.

```
return render_to_response('MeetingHub/addmeeting.html', 
    {'meetingform': meetingform, 'message':message,
    'meeting': meeting, 'participants': participants,
    #... and anything else that might be helpful to show on the page
    },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Not sure if I'd call that a "secret" ;)

Comment: tnx so muchhh,sure this is a secret :)))